# How does one debug a WCF Data Service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a **WCF Data Service** hosted in an **Asp.Net** website. here is my web.config services section :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
 <services>
     <service name="DataServiceHost"
  behaviorConfiguration="DataServiceBehavior">
  <endpoint name="DataServiceHost"
                    address=""
                    binding="webHttpBinding"
                    contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler" />
            </service>
 </services>
 <behaviors>
     <serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="DataServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
  </behavior>
```

And I have `config.UseVerboseErrors = true;` in my `InitializeService` method.

I hit `F5` I go into debug mode, and browse to my service, getting an error, though it doesn't break in VS.  I'm at a loss.

the error btw :  *The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.*

I've looked for logs... I have **ELMAH** setup for the site, nothing in there.  So I'm not sure what *service logs* it's talking about.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you "browsing to your service"?

Comment: http://localhost/services/myservice.svc I have debugging setup to use IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable error logging like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="c:\TEMP\web_messages.svclog"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Se more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx

Output file can be viewed in notedpad or in the "Service Trace Viewer" - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795.aspx

If you host in IIS you can use remote debugging: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/IISRemoteDebugging.aspx

Comment: So... there isn't a way to debug this thing running on my local machine? hosted in a website on my local machine, with the VS debugger -> attach to process method?

Comment: If it is launched from VS it is already in debug mode and you should be able to insert breakpoints as normal.
If it is running outside VS you can use the attach to process if you are running a debug build.

Comment: The problem is, I believe, that it throws the error while it's reflecting the metadata for the service, presumably because I'm missing an attribute somewhere. I've tried overriding `Handle Exception` and sticking `Debugger.Break();` in there, but it never gets hit.

Comment: And what about enabling "Thrown" for exceptions in Debug>Exceptions window? (Shortcut is Ctrl+D, E)

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can subscribe to the sendingrequest event of your objectcontext:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.sendingrequest.aspx.

Then, set a breakpoint in the event handler and inspect the request.